# jQuery autocomplete from database without JSP or PHP or richfaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, autocomplete

I am developing a JSF 2.0 application. I need to implement autocomplete on a text field from values in the Database.I am allowed to use jQuery, but I am not allowed to use jsp or php as a source for jQuery. Is there any way I can implement autocomplete in this way using jQuery? I need to specify my source as my DAO class method. Any pointers to samples are welcome.

Comment: How come you do not want to use JSP or PHP?

Comment: Just use a JSF autocomplete component? PrimeFaces has one which is using jQuery under the covers.

Comment: Is there anyway to include only the autocomplete component of primefaces or richfaces without the other styles ? I tried richfaces but it is breaking my other JS and jQuery code, and styles are differing, so wondering if there is some other way

Comment: I tried to use the example under [link]http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/example-get-autocomplete-feature-in-javajsp-with-jquery-api/            When my index.html is a standalone page the autocomplete works perfectly, but when I try to embed it into my xhtml page contriol, the autocomplete doesnt work

Comment: Look like you're completely missing the point of JSF.